# Segmentation fault while using atoi()

Tags: c

I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error when I try to run my program. I pass this into the command line
./stats 1 2 50 100
argv[3] is the number of samples, and argv[4], argv[5] are the lower and upper bounds of the sample. I'm going through it slowly to see where I get errors and I think I get seg fault when I try to assigned these to int variables

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
    {
        if (is_valid_int(argv[i]) == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s is not a valid integer\n", argv[i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    int size = atoi(argv[3]);
    int lower = atoi(argv[4]);
    int upper = atoi(argv[5]);
    printf("%d%d%d", size, lower, upper);

    generate_population(size, lower, upper);
    return 0;
}

int *generate_population(int size, int lower, int upper)
{
    int *my_array=(int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        my_array[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", my_array[0]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It does not print the values after I assign them. I tried commenting out call of `generate_population()` and I still get the error.

Comment: If you invoke your program as `./stats 1 2 50 100`, then `argv[5]` is NULL.

Comment: Errors belong on stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a valid integer\n", argv[i]); exit(1);`

Comment: How about you add some verification of the input, like you always should do. Don't make any assumptions, test for it.

Comment: Your posted code skips `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` (after the initial check), but then uses `argv[3]`  through `argv[5]`.  So it will fail if `argc < 6`.  You're missing a check for that.  Add it.

Comment: Note, `atoi()` provides ZERO error detection or reporting and will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` silently returning `0`. Use `strtol()` instead, or at least use `sscanf()` which will provide a succeed/fail indication via its return.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `./stats 1 2 50 100` argv will be `[0: "./stats", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "50", 4: "100"]`. So there is no `argv[5]`, it will be NULL on most os. The fix is:

```
int size = atoi(argv[2]);
int lower = atoi(argv[3]);
int upper = atoi(argv[4]);
```

Also you should check argc in case the user does not provide enough arguments.

Comment: It is not a fix because there are used magic numbers 2, 3, 4.:)

Comment: The C standards say that `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.